# Git push heroku master fails without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I can't push to heroku after committing changes to my local git repo. Heroku authentication works, rails app is up and running, github push still works, and heroku push used to work up until now - when `git push heroku master` from local app root directory suddenly started failing without error message. Can only interrupt with `Ctrl-C`.

Haven't found hints anywhere online yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few tips to try debugging and see what's happening. First, check the Heroku dashboard and see if Heroku is up. It's been down a few times in the past. Next, set GIT_SSH=/pathto/yourscript, where yourscript invokes ssh with -vvv (for verbose debugging). See if it's a network connectivity issue. Third, see if your repository is heavily loaded with commits (like tons of Binary files in the Git index). Ours used to be slow, when we realized this, and split it nicely so that it worked great. We also raised a Heroku support ticket to perform git gc --prune --aggressive remotely on our repo, and the problem got resolved for us.

Comment: Thank you! Should have been more patient - after waiting for a while, connection via port 22 in fact timed out, with remote hanging up. My repo is very light, don't this would be the issue. How can I tell if my network is the issue?

Comment: Got it, was just a network issue on my side. Thanks for your hints anyway!